React input component for an amount with cents
I would like to create a React component that is a custom input that works with formik.
This component is intended to receive an amount of money (for example in euros) with cents always visible.
For example, I want the default amount to be equal to 0.00 (the placeholder), but when we start to modify it, the commas do not disappear. We will therefore always have the ',00' visible.
If we press comma ',' or tab or space, then we move on to modifying the cents part of this input.
What is the best way to do this?
I tried adding a function onInput={handleInput} to my input and manipulating the cursor myself. But I find myself a little stuck because there are too many possible cases and I'm sure we can make it simpler because ultimately I want it to be a basic input behavior but with at the end a cents part always visible that we can modify if we place the cursor in the right place for example.
Here is my basic component:
import React, { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

interface CustomAmountProps {
  field: {
    name: string;
    value: string;
    onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    onBlur: (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  };
}

const CustomAmount: React.FC<CustomAmountProps> = ({ field }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const valueWidth = field.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length;
  const commaWidth = 0.5;
  const adjustedWidth = valueWidth + commaWidth;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex max-w-full">
        <input
          {...field}
          type="text"
          ref={inputRef}
          name={field.name}
          placeholder='0,00'
          className="text-[45px] font-normal border-none outline-none bg-transparent text-border flex-shrink-0 w-auto"
          value={field.value}
          style={{
            width: `${adjustedWidth}ch`,
            minWidth: '3.5ch',
          }}
        />
        <span className="text-[45px] text-border flex-grow">€</span>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full border-t border-border mt-1"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomAmount;

And here is what I tried but everything does not work well and I feel like it is too complex for nothing:
import React, { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

interface CustomAmountProps {
  field: {
    name: string;
    value: string;
    onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    onBlur: (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  };
}

const CustomAmount: React.FC<CustomAmountProps> = ({ field }) => {
    const maxAmount = 999999;
  const [value, setValue] = useState('0'); 
  const [cents, setCents] = useState('00');
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const cursorPositionRef = useRef<number>(0);

  const setRealCursorPosition = (position: number) => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(position, position);
    }
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    cursorPositionRef.current = inputRef.current?.selectionStart || 0;
  };

  const editingCents = (key: string) => {
    if (value === '0') {
      if (cursorPositionRef.current === 2) {
        setCents(key + cents.slice(1));
        cursorPositionRef.current = 3;
      } else if (cursorPositionRef.current === 3) {
        setCents(cents.charAt(0) + key);
        cursorPositionRef.current = 4;
      }
    } else {
      if (cursorPositionRef.current === value.length + 1) {
        setCents(key + cents.slice(1));
        cursorPositionRef.current += 1;
      } else if (cursorPositionRef.current === value.length + 2) {
        setCents(cents.charAt(0) + key);
        cursorPositionRef.current += 1;
      }
    }
  };

  const editingMainAmount = (key: string) => {
    if (value === '0') {
      if (cursorPositionRef.current === 0 || cursorPositionRef.current === 1) {
        setValue(key);
        cursorPositionRef.current = 1;
      }
    } else {
      if (cursorPositionRef.current === 6 && parseInt(value + key, 10) > maxAmount ) {
        return;
      } else if (value.length > 5) {
        switch (cursorPositionRef.current) {
            case 0:
                setValue(key + value.slice(1));
                cursorPositionRef.current = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                setValue(value.charAt(0) + key + value.slice(2)); 
                cursorPositionRef.current = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                setValue(value.slice(0, 2) + key + value.slice(3));
                cursorPositionRef.current = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                setValue(value.slice(0, 3) + key + value.slice(4));
                cursorPositionRef.current = 4;
                break;
            case 4:
                setValue(value.slice(0, 4) + key + value.slice(5));
                cursorPositionRef.current = 5;
                break;
            case 5:
                setValue(value.slice(0, 5) + key);
                cursorPositionRef.current = 6;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
      } else {
        const newValue = 
          value.slice(0, cursorPositionRef.current) + 
          key +                                       
          value.slice(cursorPositionRef.current);    
          
        setValue(newValue);
        cursorPositionRef.current += 1; 
      }
    }
  };


  const handleInput = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const input = e.currentTarget;
    const key = input.value.charAt(cursorPositionRef.current);

    if (key === ',' || key === 'Enter' || key === ' ') {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if (cursorPositionRef.current <= value.length) {
            cursorPositionRef.current = value.length + 1;
            setRealCursorPosition(cursorPositionRef.current)
        }
        return;
    }

    if (!/^[0-9]$/.test(key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    if (value === '0') {
        if (cursorPositionRef.current == 0 || cursorPositionRef.current == 1) {
            editingMainAmount(key);
        } else {
            editingCents(key);
        }
    } else {
        if (cursorPositionRef.current > value.length) {
            editingCents(key);
        } else {
            editingMainAmount(key);
        }
    }
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setRealCursorPosition(cursorPositionRef.current);
  }, [value, cents]);

  const valueWidth = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length;
  const commaWidth = 0.5;
  const centsWidth = cents.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length;
  const adjustedWidth = valueWidth + commaWidth + centsWidth;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex max-w-full">
        <input
          {...field}
          type="text"
          ref={inputRef}
          name={field.name}
          className="text-[45px] font-normal border-none outline-none bg-transparent text-border flex-shrink-0 w-auto"
          value={`${value},${cents}`}
          onInput={handleInput}
          onClick={onClick}
          style={{
            width: `${adjustedWidth}ch`,
            minWidth: '3.5ch',
          }}
        />
        <span className="text-[45px] text-border flex-grow">€</span>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full border-t border-border mt-1"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomAmount;

and here is the usage in my Formik form :
<div className="text-[45px] font-normal text-border">
    <Field
      name="amount"
      component={CustomAmount}
    />
    <ErrorMessage name="amount" component="div" className="text-red-500 text-sm" />
</div>

